# correct way to use passport local with passport facebook/google

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

So I have been pondering over this for some time now.

I am using passport-local for those who don't want to sign up using facebook/google and passport-google and facebook for those who prefer signing up quickly using social logins.

Since, This is my first application, I am unable to get my head around **How** I can use both of them together.

For Example, I am creating a schema to store user data

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: String,
    email: String,
    passowrd: String, 
    image: String
}) 


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The schema have password field. Now, Social Login won't send user password but for local-login we will need to use password.

The only option I can think of is creating two schema's one with password and one without password.

**Question:** Is that what people generally do? like is that the best approach to proceed with or can someone please suggest me a better alternate

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Thanks a lot for answering, I am still to go through your code. I will read and try it once in the evening (upvoted though)

Answer (score 3):

your `User schema` should be :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {type:String,required:true,default:''},
    email: {type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    email_verified:{type:Boolean,default:false},
    verify_token:{type:String,default:null},
    provider:{type:String,default:'email'},
    provider_id:{type:String,default:null},
    password: {type:String}, 
    password_reset_token:{type:String,default:null},
    image: {type:String,default:null},
    created_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
    updated_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
},{
    collection:'User'
 }); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

 module.exports.encryptPassword=function(password)
{
 var salt= bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
 var hash=  bcrypt.hashSync(password,salt,null);    
 return hash;
}


module.exports.validPassword=function(password,hash){
 return bcrypt.compareSync(password,hash);  
}
```

Here added some extra usefull fields :

- **email_verified** : for checking user has verified email or not
- **provider** : register provider like facebook , google..etc ...default
  is email if user has signup using email.
- **provider_id** : provider id is unique id of user provided by social
  media (Facebook,google)
- **password_reset_token** : is random token string , when user do forgot password and send this token with email to reset his password

> - Now , when user signup with email , save password entered by user .
> - when user signup using social media provider (facebook,google) ..then    generate a random string , create a password using bcrypt
>     and save to  password filed , remember : password field can not empty for users who signup using social media .

now create file `passport.js` :

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

var User       = require('../models/user');


module.exports = function(passport) {

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID        : 'clientID',
    clientSecret    : 'clientSecret',
    callbackURL     : 'callbackURL'

},
// facebook will send back the token and profile
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("TOKEN = "+token);
    console.log("REFRESH TOKEN = "+refreshToken);
    console.log("PROFILE = "+JSON.stringify(profile));

        // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
        User.findOne({ 'provider_id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (user) {
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } else {
                console.log(profile);
                let randomString= Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
                var newUser = new User({
                  fullName  : profile.displayName,
                  email :profile.emails[0].value, 
                  email_verified : true,
                  password : User.encryptPassword(randomString),
                  image : 'get user image from response',
                  provider : 'facebook',
                  provider_id : profile.id,    
                });

               newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
           }

        });

}));



  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID        : 'clientID',
    clientSecret    : 'clientSecret',
    callbackURL     : 'callbackURL',
  },
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

         User.findOne({ 'provider_id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
            } else {
                let randomString= Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
                var newUser = new User({
                  fullName  : profile.displayName,
                  email :profile.emails[0].value, 
                  email_verified : true,
                  password : User.encryptPassword(randomString),
                  image : 'get user image from response',
                  provider : 'google',
                  provider_id : profile.id,    
                });
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
}));


}
```

EXTRA USEFUL NOTE : when user signup using facebook/google , set `email_verified:true` , as user has already verified his email with provider ,

when user signup using his email set `email_verified:false` and generate randon token and set `verify_token:'random token'`  when creating user , then send account verification email using [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) with this random token , verification link

generate new route for handle email verification like `/verify`, when user hit link from email , this route will handle request , find user by verify_token and set `email_verified : true` , if token is correct else show error .

Hope My Answer helps you :)